# Combine 2 arrays, updating values

Tags: javascript

In my reducer I am pulling down results from my API, I would like to combine this array with the persisted data from storage if it exists, the only fields that need to be overwritten in the data are `bookMarked`, `totalScore`, and `completed`. How can I compare arrays and overwrite the required properties if they are different?

What is the best way to do this?

```
let arrayFromAPI= [
    {
        bookMarked: false,
        completed: false,
        totalScore: 50,
        current: 0,
        description:
            "<p>Lorem ipsum culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>",
        icon: "male-urinary-catheterisation",
        id: 1
    },
    {
        bookMarked: false,
        completed: false,
        totalScore: 50,
        current: 0,
        description:
            "<p>Lorem ipsum culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>",
        icon: "male-urinary-catheterisation",
        id: 2
    }
];

let arrayFromPersist = [
    {
        bookMarked: true,
        completed: false,
        totalScore: 50,
        completed: true,
        current: 0,
        description:
            "<p>Lorem ipsum culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>",
        icon: "male-urinary-catheterisation",
        id: 1
    },
    {
        bookMarked: true,
        completed: false,
        totalScore: 50,
        completed: true,
        current: 0,
        description:
            "<p>Lorem ipsum culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>",
        icon: "male-urinary-catheterisation",
        id: 2
    }
];
```

Comment: Assuming both arrays have the same length. Loop through one and compare your desired data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use filter and merge all the values from `arrayFromAPI` response to `arrayFromPersist` based on the property ID since it has to be same in both the array in order to replace the new values from `arrayFromAPI`

```js
let arrayFromAPI= [
    {
        bookMarked: false,
        completed: false,
        totalScore: 500,
        current: 250,
        description:
            "<p>Lorem ipsum culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>",
        icon: "male-urinary-catheterisation",
        id: 1
    },
    {
        bookMarked: false,
        completed: false,
        totalScore: 750,
        current: 870,
        description:
            "<p>Lorem ipsum culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>",
        icon: "male-urinary-catheterisation",
        id: 2
    }
];

let arrayFromPersist = [
    {
        bookMarked: true,
        completed: false,
        totalScore: 50,
        completed: true,
        current: 0,
        description:
            "<p>Lorem ipsum culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>",
        icon: "male-urinary-catheterisation",
        id: 1
    },
    {
        bookMarked: true,
        completed: false,
        totalScore: 50,
        completed: true,
        current: 0,
        description:
            "<p>Lorem ipsum culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>",
        icon: "male-urinary-catheterisation",
        id: 2
    }
];

function merge(a, b, prop){
  var reduced = a.filter(function(aitem){
      return ! b.find(function(bitem){
          return aitem[prop] === bitem[prop];
      });
  });
  return reduced.concat(b);
}

console.log(merge(arrayFromPersist, arrayFromAPI, "id"))
```